# Why will my images not fit to 'slick slider'

Tags: html, image, slider

This is my first post - I've just joined the community after researching through other people's questions and answers, but unfortunately I'm just lost.

I am working on a very basic portfolio website, and have beginner experience with html and css. This time, I have used a template to start me off with the responsive snippets and layout I loved, but want to learn from this myself.

My big issue is as the title states, I am unable to fit my images to the slider, eg. on a portrait image the width of the image is fitting to the width of the slider, stretching the length (to the correct ratio) so that I can only see for example 1/5 of the image with full width.
I would prefer to be able to still use both portrait and landscape images without changing their dimensions so that I can easily and regularly upload new content.
I would also be happy to use a whole new slider - my problem with replacing this is I really don't know what I'm doing here and the slider was disappearing completely when I edited it.

I have been reading the following threads with similar issues but don't know how to apply it to my own problem:
[Automatically resize image to fit Flex Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402502/automatically-resize-image-to-fit-flex-slider)

[how to fit full images perfectly into the slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305328/how-to-fit-full-images-perfectly-into-the-slider)

The HTML is a big mess, but here it is with the CSS:

```css
     .slick-slider
        {
            position: relative;

            display: block;

            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                 box-sizing: border-box;

            -webkit-user-select: none;
               -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                    user-select: none;

            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
                touch-action: pan-y;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        }

        .slick-list
        {
            position: relative;

            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;

            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .slick-list:focus
        {
            outline: none;
        }
        .slick-list.dragging
        {
            cursor: pointer;
            cursor: hand;
        }

        .slick-slider .slick-track,
        .slick-slider .slick-list
        {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
               -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .slick-track
        {
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;

            display: block;
        }
        .slick-track:before,
        .slick-track:after
        {
            display: table;

            content: '';
        }
        .slick-track:after
        {
            clear: both;
        }
        .slick-loading .slick-track
        {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .slick-slide
        {
            display: none;
            float: left;

            height: 100%;
            min-height: 1px;
        }
        [dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
        {
            float: right;
        }

        .slick-slide img
        {
          width: 100%;
          height: 450px;
          min-height: 420px;
          object-fit: cover;

            display: block;
        }
        .slick-slide.slick-loading img
        {
            display: none;
        }
        .slick-slide.dragging img
        {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .slick-initialized .slick-slide
        {
            display: block;
        }
        .slick-loading .slick-slide
        {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .slick-vertical .slick-slide
        {
            display: block;

            height: auto;

            border: 1px solid transparent;
        }
        @charset 'UTF-8';




        .slick-prev {
          left: 20px;
        }

        .slick-next {
          right: 20px;
        }
        .slick-dots{bottom: -25px;}
        .site-info{text-align:center;}
        ul.social.text-center {
          list-style-type: none;
        }
```

```html
,b.$dots=a(d).appendTo(b.options.appendDots),b.$dots.find("li").first().addClass("slick-active").attr("aria-hidden","false")}},b.prototype.buildOut=function(){var b=this;b.$slides=b.$slider.children(":not(.slick-cloned)").addClass("slick-slide"),b.slideCount=b.$slides.length,b.$slides.each(function(b,c){a(c).attr("data-slick-index",b)}),b.$slidesCache=b.$slides,b.$slider.addClass("slick-slider"),b.$slideTrack=0===b.slideCount?a('<div class="slick-track"/>').appendTo(b.$slider):b.$slides.wrapAll('<div class="slick-track"/>').parent(),b.$list=b.$slideTrack.wrap('<div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list"/>').parent(),b.$slideTrack.css("opacity",0),(b.options.centerMode===!0||b.options.swipeToSlide===!0)&&(b.options.slidesToScroll=1),a("img[data-lazy]",b.$slider).not("[src]").addClass("slick-loading"),b.setupInfinite(),b.buildArrows(),b.buildDots(),b.updateDots(),b.options.accessibility===!0&&b.$list.prop("tabIndex",0),b.setSlideClasses("number"==typeof this.currentSlide?this.currentSlide:0),b.options.draggable===!0&&b.$list.addClass("draggable")},b.prototype.buildRows=function(){var b,c,d,e,f,g,h,a=this;if(e=document.createDocumentFragment(),g=a.$slider.children(),a.options.rows>1){for(h=a.options.slidesPerRow*a.options.rows,f=Math.ceil(g.length/h),b=0;f>b;b++){var i=document.createElement("div");for(c=0;c<a.options.rows;c++){var j=document.createElement("div");for(d=0;d<a.options.slidesPerRow;d++){var k=b*h+(c*a.options.slidesPerRow+d);g.get(k)&&j.appendChild(g.get(k))}i.appendChild(j)}e.appendChild(i)}a.$slider.html(e),a.$slider.children().children().children().width(100/a.options.slidesPerRow+"%").css({display:"inline-block"})}},b.prototype.checkResponsive=function(b){var d,e,f,c=this,g=c.$slider.width(),h=window.innerWidth||a(window).width();if("window"===c.respondTo?f=h:"slider"===c.respondTo?f=g:"min"===c.respondTo&&(f=Math.min(h,g)),c.originalSettings.responsive&&c.originalSettings.responsive.length>-1&&null!==c.originalSettings.responsive){e=null;for(d in c.breakpoints)c.breakpoints.hasOwnProperty(d)&&(c.originalSettings.mobileFirst===!1?f<c.breakpoints[d]&&(e=c.breakpoints[d]):f>c.breakpoints[d]&&(e=c.breakpoints[d]));null!==e?null!==c.activeBreakpoint?e!==c.activeBreakpoint&&(c.activeBreakpoint=e,"unslick"===c.breakpointSettings[e]?c.unslick():(c.options=a.extend({},c.originalSettings,c.breakpointSettings[e]),b===!0&&(c.currentSlide=c.options.initialSlide),c.refresh())):(c.activeBreakpoint=e,"unslick"===c.breakpointSettings[e]?c.unslick():(c.options=a.extend({},c.originalSettings,c.breakpointSettings[e]),b===!0&&(c.currentSlide=c.options.initialSlide),c.refresh())):null!==c.activeBreakpoint&&(c.activeBreakpoint=null,c.options=c.originalSettings,b===!0&&(c.currentSlide=c.options.initialSlide),c.refresh())}},b.prototype.changeSlide=function(b,c){var f,g,h,d=this,e=a(b.target);switch(e.is("a")&&b.preventDefault(),h=0!==d.slideCount%d.options.slidesToScroll,f=h?0:(d.slideCount-d.currentSlide)%d.options.slidesToScroll,b.data.message){case"previous":g=0===f?d.options.slidesToScroll:d.options.slidesToShow-f,d.slideCount>d.options.slidesToShow&&d.slideHandler(d.currentSlide-g,!1,c);break;case"next":g=0===f?d.options.slidesToScroll:f,d.slideCount>d.options.slidesToShow&&d.slideHandler(d.currentSlide+g,!1,c);break;case"index":var i=0===b.data.index?0:b.data.index||a(b.target).parent().index()*d.options.slidesToScroll;d.slideHandler(d.checkNavigable(i),!1,c);break;default:return}},b.prototype.checkNavigable=function(a){var c,d,b=this;if(c=b.getNavigableIndexes(),d=0,a>c[c.length-1])a=c[c.length-1];else for(var e in c){if(a<c[e]){a=d;break}d=c[e]}return a},b.prototype.cleanUpEvents=function(){var b=this;b.options.dots===!0&&b.slideCount>b.options.slidesToShow&&a("li",b.$dots).off("click.slick",b.changeSlide),b.options.dots===!0&&b.options.pauseOnDotsHover===!0&&b.options.autoplay===!0&&a("li",b.$dots).off("mouseenter.slick",b.setPaused.bind(b,!0)).off("mouseleave.slick",b.setPaused.bind(b,!1)),b.options.arrows===!0&&b.slideCount>b.options.slidesToShow&&(b.$prevArrow&&b.$prevArrow.off("click.slick",b.changeSlide),b.$nextArrow&&b.$nextArrow.off("click.slick",b.changeSlide)),b.$list.off("touchstart.slick mousedown.slick",b.swipeHandler),b.$list.off("touchmove.slick mousemove.slick",b.swipeHandler),b.$list.off("touchend.slick mouseup.slick",b.swipeHandler),b.$list.off("touchcancel.slick mouseleave.slick",b.swipeHandler),b.$list.off("click.slick",b.clickHandler),b.options.autoplay===!0&&a(document).off(b.visibilityChange,b.visibility),b.$list.off("mouseenter.slick",b.setPaused.bind(b,!0)),b.$list.off("mouseleave.slick",b.setPaused.bind(b,!1)),b.options.accessibility===!0&&b.$list.off("keydown.slick",b.keyHandler),b.options.focusOnSelect===!0&&a(b.$slideTrack).children().off("click.slick",b.selectHandler),a(window).off("orientationchange.slick.slick-"+b.instanceUid,b.orientationChange),a(window).off("resize.slick.slick-"+b.instanceUid,b.resize),a("[draggable!=true]",b.$slideTrack).off("dragstart",b.preventDefault),a(window).off("load.slick.slick-"+b.instanceUid,b.setPosition),a(document).off("ready.slick.slick-"+b.instanceUid,b.setPosition)},b.prototype.cleanUpRows=function(){var b,a=this;a.options.rows>1&&(b=a.$slides.children().children(),b.removeAttr("style"),a.$slider.html(b))},b.prototype.clickHandler=function(a){var b=this;b.shouldClick===!1&&(a.stopImmediatePropagation(),a.stopPropagation(),a.preventDefault())},b.prototype.destroy=function(){var b=this;b.autoPlayClear(),b.touchObject={},b.cleanUpEvents(),a(".slick-cloned",b.$slider).remove(),b.$dots&&b.$dots.remove(),b.$prevArrow&&"object"!=typeof b.options.prevArrow&&b.$prevArrow.remove(),b.$nextArrow&&"object"!=typeof b.options.nextArrow&&b.$nextArrow.remove(),b.$slides&&(b.$slides.removeClass("slick-slide slick-active slick-center slick-visible").attr("aria-hidden","true").removeAttr("data-slick-index").css({position:"",left:"",top:"",zIndex:"",opacity:"",width:""}),b.$slider.html(b.$slides)),b.cleanUpRows(),b.$slider.removeClass("slick-slider"),b.$slider.removeClass("slick-initialized")},b.prototype.disableTransition=function(a){var b=this,c={};c[b.transitionType]="",b.options.fade===!1?b.$slideTrack.css(c):b.$slides.eq(a).css(c)},b.prototype.fadeSlide=function(a,b){var c=this;c.cssTransitions===!1?(c.$slides.eq(a).css({zIndex:1e3}),c.$slides.eq(a).animate({opacity:1},c.options.speed,c.options.easing,b)):(c.applyTransition(a),c.$slides.eq(a).css({opacity:1,zIndex:1e3}),b&&setTimeout(function(){c.disableTransition(a),b.call()},c.options.speed))},b.prototype.filterSlides=b.prototype.slickFilter=function(a){var b=this;null!==a&&(b.unload(),b.$slideTrack.children(this.options.slide).detach(),b.$slidesCache.filter(a).appendTo(b.$slideTrack),b.reinit())},b.prototype.getCurrent=b.prototype.slickCurrentSlide=function(){var a=this;return a.currentSlide},b.prototype.getDotCount=function(){var a=this,b=0,c=0,d=0;if(a.options.infinite===!0)d=Math.ceil(a.slideCount/a.options.slidesToScroll);else if(a.options.centerMode===!0)d=a.slideCount;else for(;b<a.slideCount;)++d,b=c+a.options.slidesToShow,c+=a.options.slidesToScroll<=a.options.slidesToShow?a.options.slidesToScroll:a.options.slidesToShow;return d-1},b.prototype.getLeft=function(a){var c,d,f,b=this,e=0;return b.slideOffset=0,d=b.$slides.first().outerHeight(),b.options.infinite===!0?(b.slideCount>b.options.slidesToShow&&(b.slideOffset=-1*b.slideWidth*b.options.slidesToShow,e=-1*d*b.options.slidesToShow),0!==b.slideCount%b.options.slidesToScroll&&a+b.options.slidesToScroll>b.slideCount&&b.slideCount>b.options.slidesToShow&&(a>b.slideCount?(b.slideOffset=-1*(b.options.slidesToShow-(a-b.slideCount))*b.slideWidth,e=-1*(b.options.slidesToShow-(a-b.slideCount))*d):(b.slideOffset=-1*b.slideCount%b.options.slidesToScroll*b.slideWidth,e=-1*b.slideCount%b.options.slidesToScroll*d))):a+b.options.slidesToShow>b.slideCount&&(b.slideOffset=(a+b.options.slidesToShow-b.slideCount)*b.slideWidth,e=(a+b.options.slidesToShow-b.slideCount)*d),b.slideCount<=b.options.slidesToShow&&(b.slideOffset=0,e=0),b.options.centerMode===!0&&b.options.infinite===!0?b.slideOffset+=b.slideWidth*Math.floor(b.options.slidesToShow/2)-b.slideWidth:b.options.centerMode===!0&&(b.slideOffset=0,b.slideOffset+=b.slideWidth*Math.floor(b.options.slidesToShow/2)),c=b.options.vertical===!1?-1*a*b.slideWidth+b.slideOffset:-1*a*d+e,b.options.variableWidth===!0&&(f=b.slideCount<=b.options.slidesToShow||b.options.infinite===!1?b.$slideTrack.children(".slick-slide").eq(a):b.$slideTrack.children(".slick-slide").eq(a+b.options.slidesToShow),c=f[0]?-1*f[0].offsetLeft:0,b.options.centerMode===!0&&(f=b.options.infinite===!1?b.$slideTrack.children(".slick-slide").eq(a):b.$slideTrack.children(".slick-slide").eq(a+b.options.slidesToShow+1),c=f[0]?-1*f[0].offsetLeft:0,c+=(b.$list.width()-f.outerWidth())/2)),c},b.prototype.getOption=b.prototype.slickGetOption=function(a){var b=this;return b.options[a]},b.prototype.getNavigableIndexes=function(){var e,a=this,b=0,c=0,d=[];for(a.options.infinite===!1?(e=a.slideCount-a.options.slidesToShow+1,a.options.centerMode===!0&&(e=a.slideCount)):(b=-1*a.options.slidesToScroll,c=-1*a.options.slidesToScroll,e=2*a.slideCount);e>b;)d.push(b),b=c+a.options.slidesToScroll,c+=a.options.slidesToScroll<=a.options.slidesToShow?a.options.slidesToScroll:a.options.slidesToShow;return d},b.prototype.getSlick=function(){return this},b.prototype.getSlideCount=function(){var c,d,e,b=this;return e=b.options.centerMode===!0?b.slideWidth*Math.floor(b.options.slidesToShow/2):0,b.options.swipeToSlide===!0?(b.$slideTrack.find(".slick-slide").each(function(c,f){return f.offsetLeft-e+a(f).outerWidth()/2>-1*b.swipeLeft?(d=f,!1):void 0}),c=Math.abs(a(d).attr("data-slick-index")-b.currentSlide)||1):b.options.slidesToScroll},b.prototype.goTo=b.prototype.slickGoTo=function(a,b){var c=this;c.changeSlide({data:{message:"index",index:parseInt(a)}},b)},b.prototype.init=function(){var b=this;a(b.$slider).hasClass("slick-initialized")||(a(b.$slider).addClass("slick-initialized"),b.buildRows(),b.buildOut(),b.setProps(),b.startLoad(),b.loadSlider(),b.initializeEvents(),b.updateArrows(),b.updateDots()),b.$slider.trigger("init",[b])},b.prototype.initArrowEvents=function(){var a=this;a.options.arrows===!0&&a.slideCount>a.options.slidesToShow&&(a.$prevArrow.on("click.slick",{message:"previous"},a.changeSlide),a.$nextArrow.on("click.slick",{message:"next"},a.changeSlide))},b.prototype.initDotEvents=function(){var b=this;b.options.dots===!0&&b.slideCount>b.options.slidesToShow&&a("li",b.$dots).on("click.slick",{message:"index"},b.changeSlide),b.options.dots===!0&&b.options.pauseOnDotsHover===!0&&b.options.autoplay===!0&&a("li",b.$dots).on("mouseenter.slick",b.setPaused.bind(b,!0)).on("mouseleave.slick",b.setPaused.bind(b,!1))},b.prototype.initializeEvents=function(){var b=this;b.initArrowEvents(),b.initDotEvents(),b.$list.on("touchstart.slick mousedown.slick",{action:"start"},b.swipeHandler),b.$list.on("touchmove.slick mousemove.slick",{action:"move"},b.swipeHandler),b.$list.on("touchend.slick mouseup.slick",{action:"end"},b.swipeHandler),b.$list.on("touchcancel.slick mouseleave.slick",{action:"end"},b.swipeHandler),b.$list.on("click.slick",b.clickHandler),b.options.autoplay===!0&&a(document).on(b.visibilityChange,b.visibility.bind(b)),b.$list.on("mouseenter.slick",b.setPaused.bind(b,!0)),b.$list.on("mouseleave.slick",b.setPaused.bind(b,!1)),b.options.accessibility===!0&&b.$list.on("keydown.slick",b.keyHandler),b.options.focusOnSelect===!0&&a(b.$slideTrack).children().on("click.slick",b.selectHandler),a(window).on("orientationchange.slick.slick-"+b.instanceUid,b.orientationChange.bind(b)),a(window).on("resize.slick.slick-"+b.instanceUid,b.resize.bind(b)),a("[draggable!=true]",b.$slideTrack).on("dragstart",b.preventDefault),a(window).on("load.slick.slick-"+b.instanceUid,b.setPosition),a(document).on("ready.slick.slick-"+b.instanceUid,b.setPosition)},b.prototype.initUI=function(){var a=this;a.options.arrows===!0&&a.slideCount>a.options.slidesToShow&&(a.$prevArrow.show(),a.$nextArrow.show()),a.options.dots===!0&&a.slideCount>a.options.slidesToShow&&a.$dots.show(),a.options.autoplay===!0&&a.autoPlay()},b.prototype.keyHandler=function(a){var b=this;37===a.keyCode&&b.options.accessibility===!0?b.changeSlide({data:{message:"previous"}}):39===a.keyCode&&b.options.accessibility===!0&&b.changeSlide({data:{message:"next"}})},b.prototype.lazyLoad=function(){function g(b){a("img[data-lazy]",b).each(function(){var b=a(this),c=a(this).attr("data-lazy"),d=document.createElement("img");d.onload=function(){b.animate({opacity:1},200)},d.src=c,b.css({opacity:0}).attr("src",c).removeAttr("data-lazy").removeClass("slick-loading")})}var c,d,e,f,b=this;b.options.centerMode===!0?b.options.infinite===!0?(e=b.currentSlide+(b.options.slidesToShow/2+1),f=e+b.options.slidesToShow+2):(e=Math.max(0,b.currentSlide-(b.options.slidesToShow/2+1)),f=2+(b.options.slidesToShow/2+1)+b.currentSlide):(e=b.options.infinite?b.options.slidesToShow+b.currentSlide:b.currentSlide,f=e+b.options.slidesToShow,b.options.fade===!0&&(e>0&&e--,f<=b.slideCount&&f++)),c=b.$slider.find(".slick-slide").slice(e,f),g(c),b.slideCount<=b.options.slidesToShow?(d=b.$slider.find(".slick-slide"),g(d)):b.currentSlide>=b.slideCount-b.options.slidesToShow?(d=b.$slider.find(".slick-cloned").slice(0,b.options.slidesToShow),g(d)):0===b.currentSlide&&(d=b.$slider.find(".slick-cloned").slice(-1*b.options.slidesToShow),g(d))},b.prototype.loadSlider=function(){var a=this;a.setPosition(),a.$slideTrack.css({opacity:1}),a.$slider.removeClass("slick-loading"),a.initUI(),"progressive"===a.options.lazyLoad&&a.progressiveLazyLoad()},b.prototype.next=b.prototype.slickNext=function(){var a=this;a.changeSlide({data:{message:"next"}})},b.prototype.orientationChange=function(){var a=this;a.checkResponsive(),a.setPosition()},b.prototype.pause=b.prototype.slickPause=function(){var a=this;a.autoPlayClear(),a.paused=!0},b.prototype.play=b.prototype.slickPlay=function(){var a=this;a.paused=!1,a.autoPlay()},b.prototype.postSlide=function(a){var b=this;b.$slider.trigger("afterChange",[b,a]),b.animating=!1,b.setPosition(),b.swipeLeft=null,b.options.autoplay===!0&&b.paused===!1&&b.autoPlay()},b.prototype.prev=b.prototype.slickPrev=function(){var a=this;a.changeSlide({data:{message:"previous"}})},b.prototype.preventDefault=function(a){a.preventDefault()},b.prototype.progressiveLazyLoad=function(){var c,d,b=this;c=a("img[data-lazy]",b.$slider).length,c>0&&(d=a("img[data-lazy]",b.$slider).first(),d.attr("src",d.attr("data-lazy")).removeClass("slick-loading").load(function(){d.removeAttr("data-lazy"),b.progressiveLazyLoad(),b.options.adaptiveHeight===!0&&b.setPosition()}).error(function(){d.removeAttr("data-lazy"),b.progressiveLazyLoad()}))},b.prototype.refresh=function(){var b=this,c=b.currentSlide;b.destroy(),a.extend(b,b.initials),b.init(),b.changeSlide({data:{message:"index",index:c}},!1)},b.prototype.reinit=function(){var b=this;b.$slides=b.$slideTrack.children(b.options.slide).addClass("slick-slide"),b.slideCount=b.$slides.length,b.currentSlide>=b.slideCount&&0!==b.currentSlide&&(b.currentSlide=b.currentSlide-b.options.slidesToScroll),b.slideCount<=b.options.slidesToShow&&(b.currentSlide=0),b.setProps(),b.setupInfinite(),b.buildArrows(),b.updateArrows(),b.initArrowEvents(),b.buildDots(),b.updateDots(),b.initDotEvents(),b.options.focusOnSelect===!0&&a(b.$slideTrack).children().on("click.slick",b.selectHandler),b.setSlideClasses(0),b.setPosition(),b.$slider.trigger("reInit",[b])},b.prototype.resize=function(){var b=this;a(window).width()!==b.windowWidth&&(clearTimeout(b.windowDelay),b.windowDelay=window.setTimeout(function(){b.windowWidth=a(window).width(),b.checkResponsive(),b.setPosition()},50))},b.prototype.removeSlide=b.prototype.slickRemove=function(a,b,c){var d=this;return"boolean"==typeof a?(b=a,a=b===!0?0:d.slideCount-1):a=b===!0?--a:a,d.slideCount<1||0>a||a>d.slideCount-1?!1:(d.unload(),c===!0?d.$slideTrack.children().remove():d.$slideTrack.children(this.options.slide).eq(a).remove(),d.$slides=d.$slideTrack.children(this.options.slide),d.$slideTrack.children(this.options.slide).detach(),d.$slideTrack.append(d.$slides),d.$slidesCache=d.$slides,d.reinit(),void 0)},b.prototype.setCSS=function(a){var d,e,b=this,c={};b.options.rtl===!0&&(a=-a),d="left"==b.positionProp?Math.ceil(a)+"px":"0px",e="top"==b.positionProp?Math.ceil(a)+"px":"0px",c[b.positionProp]=a,b.transformsEnabled===!1?b.$slideTrack.css(c):(c={},b.cssTransitions===!1?(c[b.animType]="translate("+d+", "+e+")",b.$slideTrack.css(c)):(c[b.animType]="translate3d("+d+", "+e+", 0px)",b.$slideTrack.css(c)))},b.prototype.setDimensions=function(){var a=this;a.options.vertical===!1?a.options.centerMode===!0&&a.$list.css({padding:"0px "+a.options.centerPadding}):(a.$list.height(a.$slides.first().outerHeight(!0)*a.options.slidesToShow),a.options.centerMode===!0&&a.$list.css({padding:a.options.centerPadding+" 0px"})),a.listWidth=a.$list.width(),a.listHeight=a.$list.height(),a.options.vertical===!1&&a.options.variableWidth===!1?(a.slideWidth=Math.ceil(a.listWidth/a.options.slidesToShow),a.$slideTrack.width(Math.ceil(a.slideWidth*a.$slideTrack.children(".slick-slide").length))):a.options.variableWidth===!0?a.$slideTrack.width(5e3*a.slideCount):(a.slideWidth=Math.ceil(a.listWidth),a.$slideTrack.height(Math.ceil(a.$slides.first().outerHeight(!0)*a.$slideTrack.children(".slick-slide").length)));var b=a.$slides.first().outerWidth(!0)-a.$slides.first().width();a.options.variableWidth===!1&&a.$slideTrack.children(".slick-slide").width(a.slideWidth-b)},b.prototype.setFade=function(){var c,b=this;b.$slides.each(function(d,e){c=-1*b.slideWidth*d,b.options.rtl===!0?a(e).css({position:"relative",right:c,top:0,zIndex:800,opacity:0}):a(e).css({position:"relative",left:c,top:0,zIndex:800,opacity:0})}),b.$slides.eq(b.currentSlide).css({zIndex:900,opacity:1})},b.prototype.setHeight=function(){var a=this;if(1===a.options.slidesToShow&&a.options.adaptiveHeight===!0&&a.options.vertical===!1){var b=a.$slides.eq(a.currentSlide).outerHeight(!0);a.$list.css("height",b)}},b.prototype.setOption=b.prototype.slickSetOption=function(a,b,c){var d=this;d.options[a]=b,c===!0&&(d.unload(),d.reinit())},b.prototype.setPosition=function(){var a=this;a.setDimensions(),a.setHeight(),a.options.fade===!1?a.setCSS(a.getLeft(a.currentSlide)):a.setFade(),a.$slider.trigger("setPosition",[a])},b.prototype.setProps=function(){var a=this,b=document.body.style;a.positionProp=a.options.vertical===!0?"top":"left","top"===a.positionProp?a.$slider.addClass("slick-vertical"):a.$slider.removeClass("slick-vertical"),(void 0!==b.WebkitTransition||void 0!==b.MozTransition||void 0!==b.msTransition)&&a.options.useCSS===!0&&(a.cssTransitions=!0),void 0!==b.OTransform&&(a.animType="OTransform",a.transformType="-o-transform",a.transitionType="OTransition",void 0===b.perspectiveProperty&&void 0===b.webkitPerspective&&(a.animType=!1)),void 0!==b.MozTransform&&(a.animType="MozTransform",a.transformType="-moz-transform",a.transitionType="MozTransition",void 0===b.perspectiveProperty&&void 0===b.MozPerspective&&(a.animType=!1)),void 0!==b.webkitTransform&&(a.animType="webkitTransform",a.transformType="-webkit-transform",a.transitionType="webkitTransition",void 0===b.perspectiveProperty&&void 0===b.webkitPerspective&&(a.animType=!1)),void 0!==b.msTransform&&(a.animType="msTransform",a.transformType="-ms-transform",a.transitionType="msTransition",void 0===b.msTransform&&(a.animType=!1)),void 0!==b.transform&&a.animType!==!1&&(a.animType="transform",a.transformType="transform",a.transitionType="transition"),a.transformsEnabled=null!==a.animType&&a.animType!==!1},b.prototype.setSlideClasses=function(a){var c,d,e,f,b=this;b.$slider.find(".slick-slide").removeClass("slick-active").attr("aria-hidden","true").removeClass("slick-center"),d=b.$slider.find(".slick-slide"),b.options.centerMode===!0?(c=Math.floor(b.options.slidesToShow/2),b.options.infinite===!0&&(a>=c&&a<=b.slideCount-1-c?b.$slides.slice(a-c,a+c+1).addClass("slick-active").attr("aria-hidden","false"):(e=b.options.slidesToShow+a,d.slice(e-c+1,e+c+2).addClass("slick-active").attr("aria-hidden","false")),0===a?d.eq(d.length-1-b.options.slidesToShow).addClass("slick-center"):a===b.slideCount-1&&d.eq(b.options.slidesToShow).addClass("slick-center")),b.$slides.eq(a).addClass("slick-center")):a>=0&&a<=b.slideCount-b.options.slidesToShow?b.$slides.slice(a,a+b.options.slidesToShow).addClass("slick-active").attr("aria-hidden","false"):d.length<=b.options.slidesToShow?d.addClass("slick-active").attr("aria-hidden","false"):(f=b.slideCount%b.options.slidesToShow,e=b.options.infinite===!0?b.options.slidesToShow+a:
```

(Please do tell me if I've actually been looking at the wrong section too - I have doubted myself here).

Any help would be much appreciated! I've been trying to solve this myself but I've admitted defeat - this one is too hard without being taught the correct solution! Thank you in advance.

*side note*
I would love to be able to include one video within this slider, but when I add it along with multiple pictures it is automatically excluded from the slider and placed underneath - is it possible to include it?

Comment: Your HTML is missing - only the css is in the question, and that is not correctly indicated (it is within the HTML section). Please edit your question, cut out the code, **press Ctrl+M** and add the html/css/jquery into the correct boxes. Welcome to StackOverflow !

Comment: Woops - thank you @gibberish however I can't seem to add the HTML - it is too long and I'm unsure which bit is most relevant. It's a bit of a mess!

Comment: You need to add at least the bit of HTML that includes the slider. Also, it would be very helpful to those trying to assist you to solve your problem if you create a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) - it's like using Ctrl+M but viewers can easily edit the code and troubleshoot. After creating the jsFiddle, save it and post the URL in your question (prominently displayed)

Comment: Thanks again - I've been trying to create the jsFiddle as you recommended, but it's definitely not working... I'm still trying to update and get it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/0d1yenzr/

Comment: The HTML is in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.slick-slide img {
display: block;
height: 190px; //use any height you like
width: 100% !important;
object-fit: cover;
```

}